# Qual o erro no script para gerar o calculo?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcun icon" href="imagem/contador.ico">
    <title>Contador de Pessoas</title>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Contador de Pessoas</h1>
    
    <div class="entrada">
       <h3>Entrada</h3> 
       <input type="number" name="entrada" id="entrada">
           
    </div>

    <div class="saida">
        <h3>Saída</h3>
        <input type="number" name="saida" id="saida">     

    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Total" onclick="somar">
    <p id="res">Total de Pessoas no dia:</p>
   
    <script>
        function somar(){
        var entrada = window.document.querySelector("input#entrada");
        var saida = window.document.querySelector("input#saida");
        var resultado = window.document.getElementsById("res");
        var num1 = Number(entrada.value);
        var num2 = Number(saida.value);
        var resultado = num1 - num2;
        res.innerHTML = resultado;
        }
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tem dois erros: 1 - o correto é  onclick="somar()"   :::::   2 - getElementById sem o s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem dois erros:

1. o correto é `onclick="somar()"`
2. getElementById sem o `s`

```js
        function somar(){
        var entrada = window.document.querySelector("input#entrada");
        var saida = window.document.querySelector("input#saida");
        var resultado = window.document.getElementById("res");
        var num1 = Number(entrada.value);
        var num2 = Number(saida.value);
        var resultado = num1 - num2;
        res.innerHTML = "Total de Pessoas no dia: " +resultado;
        }
```

```html
<p id="res">Total de Pessoas no dia:</p>
<div class="entrada">
       <h3>Entrada</h3> 
       <input type="number" name="entrada" id="entrada">   
</div>

<div class="saida">
        <h3>Saída</h3>
        <input type="number" name="saida" id="saida">  <input type="button" value="Total" onclick="somar()">   
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, foi falta de atenção. Erro de principiante.

Answer (score 1):

O erro que compete à sua pergunta está em atribuir o resultado em um **Element** que você não declarou.

Vou passar a correção:

```
function somar(){
    var entrada = window.document.querySelector("#entrada");
    var saida = window.document.querySelector("#saida");

    var num1 = Number(entrada.value);
    var num2 = Number(saida.value);
    var resultado = num1 - num2;

    var res = document.getElementById("res");
    res.innerText += resultado;
}
```

Também no atributo que chama a função. O correto é `<input type="button" value="Total" onclick="somar()">`.